# Pagination based on timestamp on multiple database instance setup

Tags: java, mysql

I have a setup at present there are three MySQL instance which store different data. I want to get Max combined 1000 data. The data which needs to be shown in descending order of timestamp.

for e.g.

- instance 1 has 3000 records
- instance 2 has 1000 records
- instance 3 has 500 records

---

1. Need to get records from each instance.
2. Combine all the records and from that get a max 1000 records.
3. When the user clicks next need to get data from last record ahead based on the timestamp